# How to enable onkeydown event for all keys in ACE editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I have [ACE editor](http://ace.c9.io) embedded on my site and I log the press, release times and the keyCode as the user types in their code using the `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` events, respectively. The `onkeyup` event works fine for all keys but the `onkeydown` does not work for the following keyboard keys:"Backspace", "Tab","Pause","PageUp","PageDown","End","Home","Left","Up","Right","Down","Print","Insert","Delete" and all the Numpad keys when NumLock is disabled. Thus I cannot get the press time for the mentioned keys.

I searched online for the cause(s) of this and I found out that ACE editor "blocks" the `onkeydown` events of the mentioned keys using `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()`. I then tried to edit the ace.js file to suit my needs but I failed.

Is there a way I can follow to enable `onkeydown` events for all keys without messing up the operation of the editor?

I am using ACE editor v1.3.3

Comment: Did you look at https://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto for keybindings.

Comment: It looks like they want yo to do it their way.

Comment: I managed to get the keybindings to work, thanks and I was able to extract the press times but the cursor does not move. When I remove the keybings implementations the cursor moves but I go back to stage I was at initially.

Comment: Could you create a new question for, Cursor not moving when keybindings enabled in ace editor? Also please provide a simple case scenario for the new question that recreates the bug.

Comment: Voting to close since it sounds like this question has been resolved and a new questioned should be created for the issue mentioned in comment above.